# How to improve performance using dictionary?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using excel macro to validate data fields in a table. The data contains some fields that can contain one of the values listed in the dictionary.

When I tried to run the validation macro for 700,000 records, it literally gets stuck and takes a long time to complete. Can anyone help with improving the performance of this code?

The following is a sample code I am using for one of the fields to check the content of cells in a column against a list defined in the dictionary. This never completes when run over 700,000 column records, whereas takes around 30 seconds for 50,000 column records.

```
Sub Validate_Action_Type()

'Speed Up

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

'Speed Up end


'Define the variables
Dim DicActionType As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim CountActionTypeErrors As Long
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double


'Start the timer, used to calculate elapsed time
StartTime = Timer

'Create a dictionary of allowed marker type values
DicActionType.Add "Insert", 1
DicActionType.Add "Update", 2
DicActionType.Add "Delete", 3

'Check the Marker Type Column using the dictionery created
For Each d2 In Range(Range("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown))
   If Not DicActionType.Exists(d2.Text) Then
        d2.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        CountActionTypeErrors = CountActionTypeErrors + 1
    Else
        d2.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
Next

'Calculate elapsed time
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

'Pop-up the outcome message
MsgBox "Time taken in Seconds = " & SecondsElapsed _
        & vbCrLf _
        & "Total Errors = " & CountActionTypeErrors _
        , , "Check Cells Highlighted RED"

'Restore state: undo the speed up settings

Application.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdateState
Application.DisplayStatusBar = statusBarState
Application.Calculation = calcState
Application.EnableEvents = eventsState
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = displayPageBreaksState 'note this is a sheet-level setting

End Sub
```

Comment: do you have to validate columns cells on three values ("Insert", "Update" and "Delete")? Furthermore your code doesn't loop through columns

Comment: I am unable to duplicate your timings.  Checking 30,000 rows and finding 100 errors takes 1.08 seconds.  As I increased the number of rows, the increase in time was linear at about 1 second per 30,000 rows.  The number of errors makes little difference.  Checking 700,000 rows and finding 10,000 errors took 24.05 seconds.  Checking 700,000 rows and finding 70,000 errors took 24.52 seconds.

Comment: As Tony already mentioned, the existing code should increase linearly in time as number of rows increase.  You **might** be able to improve on overall time though by doing `Range(Range("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone` before the loop instead of `d2.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone` inside the loop.

Comment: @user3598756 - Yes - your understanding is correct. That's what I am trying to do. The code doesn't loop through columns. Other columns have similar validations but for different list of values.

Comment: I should have mentioned that with random OS functions firing at any moment, 24.05 and 24.52 are effectively equal.  I had thought about the change that @YowE3K suggests but decided that your timings are so different from mine that you must have another problem.  I have now deleted `d2.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone` from the loop and added `Columns(3).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone` before the loop.  This reduced the processing of 700,000 rows to 9.41 seconds. A worthwhile saving in time.

Comment: @Tony - That's strange. On my machine, the code takes more than 200 seconds for 700,000 rows or the excel even gets stuck at times.  Is there a way to reduce the time further in general?

Comment: @YowE3K - Thanks, that's an awesome tip. It reduced the execution time from 200 seconds to 48 seconds. Can there be a way to bring this down further?

Comment: @TonyDallimore - Yes - the reduction is significant with that change. But, still that takes 41 seconds for 700K rows on my machine! Looking for methods to bring this execution time down further.

Comment: Also - it would be interesting how would the timing scale as I increase the list size in the dictionary? One of the variables has as many as 32 listed values in the dictionary!

Comment: I will investigate where the time is going on my system and post an answer explaining the nature of that investigation.  However, your timings are much worse than mine. Why? My system has a 2.5 GHz, 64-bit  processor with 8 Gb of Ram. Your system being significantly slower may explain the difference. As I write, HP Support Solutions Framework is consuming 53% of my CPU time and 34% of my RAM. That only runs on Sunday.  Do you have any background processes that permanently consume resources?

Comment: @TonyDallimore - No, I don't see any significant background process. I am also curious to know if this is the smartest VBA implementation even for dictionary list with larger sizes (currently dictionary has only three values - Insert, Update, Delete)?

Comment: Its not the dictionary, that is slowing your sub down. Its the number of accesses to the worksheet. Did you think about using conditional formatting to achieve your goals? Otherwise reducing accesses to the worksheet helps improving the performance (sse my answer beloe).

Comment: @Jochen - Thank you so much. Have achieved the best timing of ~2 seconds for 700K records with your solution with no error. Phew! What a journey from nowhere to 2 seconds!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing cells is always very slow. As you want to color your cells, you need a reference, but only for coloring, not for checking. For checking you can use a much faster array.

In the following code I used an array to check the actions. On my machine its about 5 times faster having ~17% errors in my sample cells.

```
Sub Validate_Action_Type()

'Speed Up

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

'Speed Up end


'Define the variables
Dim DicActionType As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim CountActionTypeErrors As Long
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim ActionArr, I As Integer


ActionArr = Range(Range("D2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Value

'Start the timer, used to calculate elapsed time
StartTime = Timer

'Create a dictionary of allowed marker type values
DicActionType.Add "Insert", 1
DicActionType.Add "Update", 2
DicActionType.Add "Delete", 3

'Check the Marker Type Column using the dictionery created
Columns("C").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
For I = 1 To UBound(ActionArr)
   If Not DicActionType.Exists(ActionArr(I, 1)) Then
        'ActionArr(I, 2) = 3
        Cells(I + 1, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        CountActionTypeErrors = CountActionTypeErrors + 1
    Else
        ActionArr(I, 2) = 0
    End If
Next I

'Calculate elapsed time
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

'Pop-up the outcome message
MsgBox "Time taken in Seconds = " & SecondsElapsed _
        & vbCrLf _
        & "Total Errors = " & CountActionTypeErrors _
        , , "Check Cells Highlighted RED"

'Restore state: undo the speed up settings

Application.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdateState
Application.DisplayStatusBar = statusBarState
Application.Calculation = calcState
Application.EnableEvents = eventsState
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = displayPageBreaksState 'note this is a sheet-level setting

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Jochen - this was helpful. I have made the DicActionType.Add statements more dynamic by adding such list in an excel column.

Answer (score 0):

As promised I have investigated what the time is going on my laptop.  Without knowing which statements are the slowest, you can easily spend your time optimising sections of your code that have little effect on the duration.  There is a lot of bad advice available based on people assumptions about what is slow.  `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` will save very significant amounts of time.  Other changes are often of little significance.  It appears there is some significant overhead with calling `WorksheetFunction` from VBA because I have yet to find one that is faster than VBA.  Unless someone says “I have run timings”, don’t believe them.

I will explain my implementation of your code and then tell you what I discovered.  You will need to concatenate the blocks of code below if you wish to perform similar tests on your computer.

```
Option Explicit
  Const ColCrnt As Long = 3
  Const NumNames As Long = 30
  Const RowDataFirst As Long = 2
  Const RowMax As Long = 700000
  Const ErrorMax As Long = 70000
```

I have used constants to specify values I might wish to vary between test runs.

I never changed `ColCrnt` from 3 (= C) or `RowDataFirst` from 2 since I do not believe their values are relevant.

I tried much lower values for `RowMax` and `ErrorMax` at first but most of my timings were with the values shown.  My tests were with 10% errors.  I am sure your data is much better so my timings for worksheet updates should be much worse than yours.

I have called the values you place in a dictionary, “names” or “valid names” so `NumNames`is the constant I have changed the most.

```
Sub CtrlCheckAll()

  Call CtrlCheck1
  Call CtrlCheck1
  Call CtrlCheck1

End Sub
```

I created three variations of your code.  This routine allowed me to call all three in one go.  It became clear that variations 2 and 3 were not significantly faster or slower than variation 1.  In the end, I just used this routine to call variation 1 three times.

When you look at the timings, you will see how much variation there is from run to run. Most of this variation is probably background processes (task manager, virus checkers and the like).  However, Excel also has background tasks (such as garbage collection). I prefer much longer test runs because they give more stable timings.  Apart from increasing the number of rows, I am not sure how to slow your routine down; I have settled for running it several times and averaging their separate durations.

```
Sub CtrlCheck1()

  Dim CountActionTypeErrors As Long
  Dim d2 As Variant
  Dim ExistsCrnt As Boolean
  ‘Dim InxVn As Long
  Dim ValidNames As New Dictionary
  Dim TimeCheckStart As Single
  Dim TimeExistsTotal As Single
  Dim TimeStart As Single
  Dim TimeWshtTotal As Single
  Dim Wsht As Worksheet

  Set Wsht = Worksheets("Data")

  TimeStart = Timer
  Call GenDic(ValidNames, NumNames)
  Debug.Print "Create time " & Format(Timer - TimeStart, "00.00000")

  'TimeStart = Timer
  'For InxVn = 0 To ValidNames.Count - 1
  '  Debug.Print ValidNames.Keys(InxVn)
  'Next
  'Debug.Print "Access time " & Format(Timer - TimeStart, "00.00000")

  TimeStart = Timer

  Call GenWsht(Wsht:=Wsht, RowDataFirst:=RowDataFirst, ColCrnt:=ColCrnt, _
               RowMax:=RowMax + RowDataFirst - 1, _
               ErrorMax:=ErrorMax, Dic:=ValidNames)
  Debug.Print "Build worksheet time " & Format(Timer - TimeStart, "00.000")

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  TimeExistsTotal = 0!
  TimeWshtTotal = 0!
  TimeCheckStart = Timer
```

You will recognise some of the variables while others have been introduced by me.

Your code accesses the active worksheet.  This relies on the user having the correct worksheet active when the macro is started.  You would not do this if you had ever had to fix the mess caused by a user running a macro against the wrong worksheet and not having a backup of the undamaged worksheet.  Being explicit about the worksheet to be accessed makes your code clearer, reduces the opportunities for disaster and has no noticeable time penalty.

I have not given you the code for `GenDic` since you have your own real data.  However, I will add the code if you want it.  Notice, I have placed `Timer` around this call.  I wanted to know if creating a dictionary was slow process.  I discovered the duration was less than `Timer` can accurately record.  Normally the duration was given as zero thousandths of a second although occasionally it was four thousandths of a second

I have commented out the code to list the keys in the dictionary because it was creating too many lines.  Again my motive was to see if accessing keys was slow but again the duration was less than `Timer` can accurately record.

I have not given you the code for `GenWsht` since you have your own real data.  Again, I will add the code if you want it.

The last three statements of the above block are the important ones.  `TimeCheckStart` is used to calculate the total duration of the main block of code.  `TimeExistsTotal` and `TimeWshtTotal`are used to accumulate the duration of the two statements of thought might be the most expensive in terms of time.  I will explain them later.

```
  With Wsht

    For Each d2 In Range(.Cells(RowDataFirst, ColCrnt), _
                         .Cells(RowDataFirst, ColCrnt).End(xlDown))

      TimeStart = Timer
      ExistsCrnt = ValidNames.Exists(d2.Text)
      TimeExistsTotal = TimeExistsTotal + Timer - TimeStart

      If Not ExistsCrnt Then
        TimeStart = Timer
        d2.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        TimeWshtTotal = TimeWshtTotal + Timer - TimeStart
        CountActionTypeErrors = CountActionTypeErrors + 1
     End If
    Next

  End With
```

This is a slightly modified version of the critical part of your code. As explained earlier, I access cells in a named worksheet.  I do not believe this could have a noticeable

I have split the test for a name existing out of the `If` statement so I can place `Timer` statements around the test.  This probably has a minor effect on the duration but you cannot add timer statements without having an effect. Note that what these `Timer` statements are doing is accumulating the total duration of these tests.  I have also places `Timer` statements around `d2.Interior.ColorIndex = 3`

```
  Debug.Print "##### Check 1 #####"
  Debug.Print "      Number rows " & RowMax
  Debug.Print "    Number errors " & ErrorMax
  Debug.Print "      Valid names " & ValidNames.Count
  Debug.Print " Total check time " & Format(Timer - TimeCheckStart, "00.000")
  Debug.Print "Total exists time " & Format(TimeExistsTotal, "00.000")
  Debug.Print "  Total wsht time " & Format(TimeWshtTotal, "00.000")
```

End Sub

This is the final block of variation 1 of my code.

Two of my timings were:

```
 Total check time  12.766   9.820 
Total exists time  10.031   7.852
  Total wsht time   2.152   1.543
```

The first issue to notice is the difference between the two sets of figures with the first run taking 33% more time than the second.  This is typical of the variation you will get in the duration of short runs.

The second issue is that the total duration of the two timed statements is around .6 seconds less that the total duration.  This is to be expected since all the other statement take some time; there is no expensive statement yet to find.  Since your durations are so much longer than mine, you need to review your timings and perhaps test other statements if your unexplained duration is excessive.

The last issue is that the total duration of the worksheet update is so much less that the existence check.  Since 10% of my data is faulty which I assume far exceeds your error rate, your worksheet update time should be much, much less than mine.  Optimising the worksheet update would have minimal effect on the total duration.

With variation 2, the inner code is:

```
RowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColCrnt).End(xlUp).Row

For RowCrnt = RowDataFirst To RowLast

  TimeStart = Timer
  ExistsCrnt = ValidNames.Exists(.Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Text)
  TimeExistsTotal = TimeExistsTotal + Timer - TimeStart

  If Not ExistsCrnt Then
    TimeStart = Timer
    .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    TimeWshtTotal = TimeWshtTotal + Timer - TimeStart
    CountActionTypeErrors = CountActionTypeErrors + 1
 End If
Next
```

Here I have used a `For Loop` instead of a `For Each Loop`.  It is not clear from my timings which is faster.  I will not bother to test further.  I would use whichever I found more convenient even if I knew one was fractionally faster than the other.

For variation 3, I introduced a `With statement` for the cell:

```
  With Wsht

    RowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColCrnt).End(xlUp).Row

    For RowCrnt = RowDataFirst To RowLast

      With .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt)

        TimeStart = Timer
        ExistsCrnt = ValidNames.Exists(.Text)
        TimeExistsTotal = TimeExistsTotal + Timer - TimeStart

        If Not ExistsCrnt Then
          TimeStart = Timer
          .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
          TimeWshtTotal = TimeWshtTotal + Timer - TimeStart
          CountActionTypeErrors = CountActionTypeErrors + 1
       End If

       End With

    Next

  End With
```

This does look to be faster than variation 2, as expected, and perhaps a little faster than variation 1 but the evidence for these conclusions is poor.

Here are the timings:

[image: Timings]

In the bold lines, the timings are averages of the individual run times shown below.

The big reveal from this is that the size of the dictionary has no effect on run time.

My investigation has revealed nothing that would help you.  I have explained how I created my timings and how I interpreted those timings so you can test what is different about your system.

Comment: Thanks Tony for this extensive research on timing. I loved the result that dictionary size doesn't affect much the execution time. One last bit, how about using an array as recommended by Jochen below? That could improve the performance.

Comment: If the entries in an array are unsorted, you can only test for existence of a key by searching from the beginning.  If the entries are sorted, you can use a binary search which is much faster but this still takes longer and longer as the array increases in size. I do not know the details of Microsoft's implementation but I know the theory. A hashing algorithm is run on your key to turn it into a number which identifies the "bucket" into which the item is placed. If the number of buckets is well defined, there will only be one or two items in each bucket which is why the access is fast.